# Java upgrade 8 to 11 causing issue with LDAPS connection (Connection or outbound has closed)

Tags: java, ldap

This issue seen after java upgrade. LDAP with DNS alias does not connect with java 11.0.2 where as it worked with java 8

DNS alias as below this remain same no change here only change is java upgrade 8 to 11:

```
$ nslookup ad1.XXXXX.zz

    Server:         10.222.249.209
    Address:        10.222.249.209#53
    
    Name:   ad1.XXXXX.zz
    Address: 10.222.249.205
    Name:   ad1.XXXXX.zz
    Address: 10.222.249.204
    Name:   ad1.XXXXX.zz
    Address: 10.222.249.210
```

LDAP direct IP with java 11.0.2 it works no issue:

```
$ nslookup qdegsf.XXXXX.zz

    Server:         10.222.249.209
    Address:        10.222.249.209#53
    
    Name:   qdegsf.XXXXX.zz
    Address: 10.222.249.210
```

Process parameters:

```
/opt/3rdparty/jdk_installed/jdk-11.0.2/bin/java -Dsserver -Djdk.serialFilter=*  -Dfile.encoding=UTF8  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/3rdparty/tomcat/conf/svrtrust -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=XXXX -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/3rdparty/tomcat/conf/svrkeystore.jks
```

Below is the issue traces when ldap connection is made

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: connection to ldap server failed;url;ldaps://ad1.XXXXX.zz:636;authDN;sa_XXX@XXXXX.zz
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: ad1.XXXXX.zz:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed]
java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed
Trace for the thrown exceptions:
java.lang.RuntimeException: connection to ldap server failed;url;ldaps://ad1.XXXXX.zz:636;authDN;sa_XXX@XXXXX.zz
    at auth.ldap.LdapConnection.testConnection(LdapConnection.java:46)

    
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: ad1.XXXXX.zz:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:219)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2795)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:320)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:730)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:208)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:101)
    at auth.ldap.LdapConnection.testConnection(LdapConnection.java:41)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:976)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:398)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:371)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(LdapClient.java:359)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:214)
    ... 15 more
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: ad1.XXXXX.zz:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:219)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2795)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:320)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:730)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:208)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:101)
    at auth.ldap.LdapConnection.testConnection(LdapConnection.java:41)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:976)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:398)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:371)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(LdapClient.java:359)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:214)
    ... 15 more
java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:976)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:398)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:371)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(LdapClient.java:359)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:214)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2795)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:320)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:730)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:208)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:101)
    at nims.auth.ldap.LdapConnection.testConnection(LdapConnection.java:41)
    at auth.LdapAuthenticationService.doTestConnection(LdapAuthenticationService.java:50)
```

Update getting below error when:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect  ad1.XXXXX-ru.zz:636

CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 
verify error:num=20:**unable to get local issuer certificate**
verify return:1
depth=0 
verify error:num=27:**certificate not trusted**
verify return:1
depth=0 
verify error:num=21:**unable to verify the first certificate**
verify return:1

Certificate chain
 0 s:
   i:/DC=zz/DC=XXXXX-ru/CN=XXXXX-ru-ROOT-CA

Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFfjCCBGagAwIBAgITLwAAAKgllUHEZUjzRwAAAAAAqDANBgkqhkiG9w0BA.................

APpwNrloBJjZo2bJ7pqe4gXN
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

subject=
issuer=/DC=zz/DC=XXXXX-ru/CN=XXXXX-ru-ROOT-CA

No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, prime256v1, 256 bits

SSL handshake has read 1980 bytes and written 441 bytes

New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
    Session-ID: C51900006745E495E1C8CA132C0EDF901C3638DE9E5EEA506551E298E2374372
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: A8B4C4E2B01FE11822CE047D3B7D692EE1C001DA551DFE63FBC314737177BE7A285F79D6FF36B67D3E1AFF72C1402D2D
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1574232095
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrote a test script to connect with ldap ( with ssl logs enable) @ jdk 11

```
/opt/soft/jdk_installed/jdk-11.0.2/bin/java -XX:+UseSerialGC -DLdapsConnect -Djavax.net.debug=all -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/soft/tomcat/conf/svrtrust -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=hsqlIiza -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/soft/tomcat/conf/svrkeystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=hsqlIiza -classpath /tmp/ LdapsConnect $*
```

found that below error in ssl logs

```
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|1D|Thread-0|2020-01-22 10:55:21.632 CET|TransportContext.java:313|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): No subject alternative DNS name matching ad1.xxxx.zz found.
```

Conclusion/Solution : Ldap certificate should be modified to have ad1.ngssm-ru.zz which is missing.
As Java 8u181 has changes as below in ldap support which does not allow old way after java version 8u181 and above.

Java is trying to make sure the host name in your connection configuration matches the host names in the remote LDAPS TLS server certificate and that those host names in the certificate are valid. The correct solution for a secure connection is to have your LDAP server administrators correct the LDAPs certificate the ldap server is using so that the improved endpoint identification algorithms work. This is for our protection.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u181-relnotes-4479407.html
Changes
core-libs/javax.naming
? Improve LDAP support
Endpoint identification has been enabled on LDAPS connections.

To improve the robustness of LDAPS (secure LDAP over TLS) connections, endpoint identification algorithms have been enabled by default.

Note that there may be situations where some applications that were previously able to successfully connect to an LDAPS server may no longer be able to do so. Such applications may, if they deem appropriate, disable endpoint identification using a new system property: `com.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification`.

Define this system property (or set it to true) to disable endpoint identification algorithms.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the version of Java 8 you were using, there could be several reasons for this error:

- Java 11 (and recent versions of Java 8) now enforce hostname
  verification when establishing SSL connections. So the server's
  certificate much match the hostname you are trying to connect to.
- Java 11 also has newer cipher suites and TLS versions, and deprecated some old cipher suites. You may want to enable SSL
  debugging to see what is exchanged on the SSL layer.
- Finally, there are several issues with TLS(1.3), cipher suites in the early versions of Java 11, so you might want to switch to the
  latest update (11.0.5)

Comment: Thanks Ludovic, I tried enabling few thing like below did not work :
 
1)  -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1"

2) -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true

also tried generating ssl logs with -Djavax.net.debug=all
it does not geneate looks like some thing wrong 
i'll check here and update the outcome

Comment: In my case re-enabling TLSv1 helped. It is as easy as defining property:

-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1

Of course you can need also other protocols, so you can specify full list:

    -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3

Comment: Beware, that some docker images (Redhat ubi8) have `/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config` which explicitly disables some protocols, including TLSv1

Comment: I just went through all this (upgrading from java 8 to 11). FWIW, the thing that worked for me was adding to the keystore the intermediate certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You can change default params like RSA keysize etc. by modifying the file `java.security`. However, please be aware that there is a second file `java.config` (on Linux it is located: `/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config`) that overrides the params in `java.security`.

This is controlled by the property (in `java.security`):

`security.useSystemPropertiesFile=true`

So, either change that property to `false`, or modify params directly in `java.config`.

I was stuck with that for a long time!