# The path for certificate, private key and pfx files for OpenDJ version 3.0 install to be completed

Tags: opendj

I am new to `OpenDJ` from ForgeRock. I installed version `3.0` on `rhel 7` server along with `Java version: 1.8.0_251` by following this instruction: https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/opendj/3/install-guide/#chap-install. After install is completed with `no ssl/tls`, system threw...

```
Error reading configuration. Details:
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: 0.0.0.0:4444 [Root
exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present]
```

After talking to our sys admin, I decided to give proper `hostname/fqdn` and obtained `opendj.doamin.com.key, opendj.domain.com.crt and opendj.domain.com.pfx` files.

```
hostname: opendj
domain: domain.com
```

My question is I am about to reinstall it but in where I have to place them so that I may avoid aforementioned exception? I'd like to believe the exception was thrown due to missing cert file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it's missing the certificate file. It's most likely due to a change of behavior of JDNI with an update of JDK8.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58930712/738708.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your feedback. Bear with me should I upgrade Java or downgrade it? I read ^ link but I wasn't sure...