# opendj control panel CertificateException

Tags: opendj

After install opendj3.0.0 in my PC windows10 [with the GUI](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/opendj/3/install-guide/#gui-install), I want to administer the local server with `OpenDJ Control Panel`. Unfortunately I got an error `CertificateException`. What special steps should I have to take to run `OpenDJ Control Panel` to connect the local server?

[image]

Cancelling that dialog, the control panel shows up with "Authentication Required".
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely due to a change of behavior of JDNI with an update of JDK8. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58930712/738708.

Comment: Java version in my PC is jdk1.8.0_241 whose JAVA_HOME is `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241`. So I can try out other versions?

Comment: You should try the workaround which is to add the Java argument -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true

Comment: Adding that Java Argument at Launch Command in control-panel.bat file really works. Thanks Ludovic.